# Excluding files whilst using tar to zip site contents not working

Tags: shell, ssh, command-line, tar

I'm trying to zip the contents of a site using `tar` and exclude a bunch of folders and `error_log` files but it doesn't seem to be working, when it's processing I still see many of the excluded files being processed.

I am in the root of the site and I am trying to `tar` everything inside of `public_html`.

Here is the command I am running:

```
tar -zcvf files-live.tgz public_html/ --exclude='public_html/cache' --exclude='public_html/uplimg' --exclude='public_html/images/listings' exclude='public_html/sets' exclude='public_html/manage' exclude='error_log'
```

**Side Note:** `error_log` exists in several directories but I don't want *any* of them included.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used `exclude=` instead of `--exclude=`.

```
 tar -zcvf files-live.tgz public_html/ --exclude='public_html/cache' --exclude='public_html/uplimg' --exclude='public_html/images/listings' --exclude='public_html/sets' --exclude='public_html/manage' --exclude='error_log'
```

Comment: Ahh crap, stupid error by me. What do you mean I don't need to exclude `error_log`? This file exists in several sub-directories of `public_html` as well as inside `public_html`.

Comment: @Brett I thought `error_log` was a directory in the same folder as `public_html`. I didn't know that people would make `error_log` accessible by http.

Comment: No, error_log are files created by the server which end up in a whole range of directories.